# Value undefined in global variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, swagger

I have this component where I am trying to extract information from two interfaces, one called StatisticsLeague from where I get the id of the team and another one called leagues, which accesses the League interface to get the id of the league.

I am trying that these values appear in the mat-select, but the values are returned in console as undefined.

Where am I wrong?

```
export class StatisticsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  statisticsLeague: StatisticsLeague[] | any;
  selectedSwitch = SelectSwitch;
  showSelect: boolean = false;
  teams: Autocomplete[] = [];
  selectedLeague: Autocomplete | null;
  selectedTeam: Autocomplete | null;
  @Input() leagues: Autocomplete[] = [];

  constructor(private statisticsService: StatisticsService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ leagues, teams }) => {
      this.leagues =
        leagues && Array.isArray(leagues.data)
          ? leagues.data.map((item: Leagues) => ({ uuid: item.id, name: item.name }))
          : [];
      this.teams =
        teams && Array.isArray(teams.data)
          ? teams.data.map((item: Leagues) => ({ uuid: item.id, name: item.name }))
          : [];
    });
    console.log(this.selectedLeague);
    console.log(this.selectedTeam);
  }

 getStatisticsLeaguesAndTeams(leagueId: string, teamId: string) {
    this.selectedLeague = this.leagues.find((item) => item.uuid === leagueId) ?? null;
    this.selectedTeam = this.teams.find((item) => item.uuid === teamId) ?? null;
    this.statisticsService.getStatisticsByLeagueByTeam(leagueId, teamId).subscribe(data =>{
      this.statisticsLeague = data;
      console.log(this.statisticsLeague);
    })
  }
```

and I have my html which is this

````
```

<div class="mat-select">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Liga</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedLeague">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let league of leagues" [value]="league.name">
        {{ league.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>    
<div class="mat-select" *ngIf="statisticsLeague">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Equipo</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTeam">
      <mat-option [value]="statisticsLeague.teamId">{{ statisticsLeague.nombreEquipo }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

```
````

Could you help me to solve it?

value in console: undefined

Comment: Try move the ```console.log(this.selectedLeague)``` and ```console.log(this.selectedTeam)``` inside ```this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ leagues, teams }) => { ..//here });``` if data is being loaded, before using it in ```getStatisticsLeaguesAndTeams(leagueId: string, teamId: string) { .. }```.

Comment: Keep dialing undefined

Comment: You aren't assigning this.selectedLeague, this.selectedTeam inside ngOnInit. I don't see calling of getStatisticsLeaguesAndTeams method. So, what do you expect?